# Absolute value of the sume of two complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I have a question about the following.

$|A+B|^2$, where $A, B $ is complex number. The question is , when can

$|A+B|^2$  be equal to $|A|^2 + |B|^2$?

Comment: It would likely help to write $A$ as $a+\alpha i$ and $B$ as $b+\beta i$ and then just start calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Vectors $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal.

Comment: what? can you pleas write it out?

Comment: @kuku Because modulus is a distance from 0, you have Pythagorean theorem.